# XMLHttpRequest call is never being made to the server

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest

I have an XMLHttpRequest that appears fine, it doesn't generate any error I can see but I never see the request sent to the server.

Its like its erroring out, or cancelling, even before the call to the server is made.  There is no network request in dev tools networking section.

The biggest thing I notice is that although I am setting `xhr.timeout = 15000`, the timeout in the xhr object states its `0` - but I don't know if this an issue.

Here is my Request, the only thing printing to console in the response processing is the `XHR OTHER` console message:

```
function sendError(url,params) {
  return new Promise( function(resolve) {
    //url - passed from calling function
    //params - JSON.stringify({ var1:var1,var2:var2}) ; - passed from calling script
    console.log(url) ;  // prints proper url to console
    console.log(params) ; // prints proper params to console
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'json' ;
    //var params = JSON.stringify({ type:8,subject:sub.value,message:msg.value,emailAddys:toAddresses }) ;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      var status ;
      if (xhr.readyState == 15) {
        console.log("XHR Tiemout") ;
        console.log("Time out ready state = 15") ;
        status = {status:false,errMsg:"Time out ready state = 15"} ;
      } else if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log("XHR Response") ;
        console.log(xhr.response) ;
        var res = xhr.response[0] ;
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          // process API call results
          status = {status:true,errMsg:res.message} ;
        } else {
          status = {status:false,errMsg:res.message} ;
        }
      } else {
        console.log("XHR OTHER") ;  <----- this prints to console everytime
        console.log(xhr) ;
        status = {status:false,errMsg:"Something went wrong, no response from server"} ;
      }
      resolve(status) ;
    }
    
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Pragma' , 'no-cache') ;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Expires' , -1) ; 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control' , 'no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate') ;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type' , 'application/json') ;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With' , 'com.mydomain') ;
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization' , 'Token ' +clientToken) ;
        xhr.timeout = 15000 ;  // 15 seconds
        xhr.ontimeout = function() { console.log("Timed Out!") ; };
        xhr.send(params);        
      }) ;
    }
```

And here is the xhr i am printing to console, there is a sendError in the `onreadystatechange()` function, but I don't understand the root of the error:

[image: xhr object]

Comment: Is this a cross origin request (different port or domain or subdomain than page)? Do you see any CORS errors in dev tools console?

Comment: @charlietfl - no, not a CORS error, not even getting the call to the server.  Nothing shows in the dev tools networking section.  Its like its erroring out, or cancelling, even before the call is made.

Comment: Does the network tab show any other requests?

Comment: `console.log("XHR OTHER") ;` — is going to run no matter what you do: the ready state changes through several states before it reaches DONE. You're also `resolve()`ing your promise the first time the readystate changes instead of waiting for it to be DONE.

Comment: @Quentin - thanks.  your comments clued me in to what I was doing wrong.  Had to go back and reread xmlhttprequest specs - i was doing a few things wrong.